# How to measure multiline text height in OS X 10.11?

Tags: macos, nsstring, osx-yosemite, nstableview, osx-elcapitan

Problem: I want to set long text in view-based NSTableView cell where the row height is to be adjusted appropriately. For this I need to calculate the height of the text bounding rectangle. 
I found solution: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4216370?tstart=0 but it uses functions deprecated in 10.11.
So the fundamental question is: how to measure bounding rectangle of multiline/line-broken text while ensuring its conformance with OS X 10.11?

Comment: The first example from the link works for me. What did you try, and what deprecation warnings did you get?

Comment: According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/  the function *initWithContainerSize:* is deprecated in OS X 10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the header file, you should use `-initWithSize:` instead of `-initWithContainerSize:`. Not sure why that's not mentioned in the documentation. Of course, if you need to be able to run your code on versions before 10.11, then you'll have to conditionally call either `-initWithSize:` or `-initWithContainerSize:`, depending on the current version.

```
    NSTextContainer *container;
    if ([NSTextContainer instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithSize:)]) {
        container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize: NSMakeSize(width, FLT_MAX)];
    } else {
        container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize: NSMakeSize(width, FLT_MAX)];
    }
```

Weirdly, I don't actually get a deprecation warning when I build a project that uses the old initializer with the 10.11 SDK.

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't bother with the two code paths for deploying to earlier versions. Just keep using the deprecated method and ignore or suppress the warning. It will keep working for a good long while. The two-code-paths approach doesn't avoid the warning, anyway. Having two code paths means that one is likely to be untested. It's extra opportunity for bugs. Etc.

Comment: I had the same thought, but if they want to both use the right API, and be able to run on earlier versions, you gotta do something like that.